# How do I get a sound when I click a button in a website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I created it on Visual Studio, using asp.net. Here is what my programming looks like, but it doesnt play a sound, when i click on the button.

[image]

Comment: Don't use image of text, include text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Click() events run on the *server* not the client. So unless you want a screaming data center what you are doing is the wrong approach. Instead you need to use javascript.

First put the MP3 file somewhere within your web site, rather than an embedded resource.

Then inside your code behind method for your click event you'd call

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
   this.GetType(), 
   "PlayScream", 
   "var audio= new Audio('pathtomp3.mp3');audio.Play();",
   true);
```

This will insert javascript into your page after the postback when the page reloads.

Answer (score -1):

When a SoundPlayer is constructed with a stream being inputted, a .wav file is expected.
[This](http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav) may help you.

Also consider naming your audio file with better style.